# AngularJS and D3 - JavaScript RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in recursion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, solr

SEE EDIT BELOW

I wrote a function to recursively parse solr facet.pivot output and massage it into something I can feed into d3 for a sunburst diagram. Everything works but I am getting one of these and I am not sure how to go about it.

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Here is the function with some extra statements for readability.

```
this.get_facet_pivot_sunburst = function(field, data) {
    if (!field) {
        return {};
    } else {
        if (!data) {
            data = response['facet_counts']['facet_pivot'][field];
        }
        var ops = 0;
        var d = parse_facet_pivot(data);    
        console.log("Operations" + ops);
        return d;
    } 

    function parse_facet_pivot(data){
      var out = {'name' : 'root', 'children': []};
      for (ob in data) {
        ops++;
        out.children.push(parse_item(data[ob]));
      }
      return out;
    }

    function parse_item (doc) {
      ops++;
      var t = {'name' : doc.value, 'size' : doc.count, 'children': []};
      for (piv in doc.pivot) {
        t.children.push(parse_item(doc.pivot[piv]));
      }
      return t;
    }
}
```

I read online that it may be related to passing a large object to a method or heavy recursion, however I've tried to limit the data to a small subset and I still get this error. In this case, the logger printed 12 as the number of operations, however generally it is between 300-400.

To provide some more background, this runs in an angularjs service, to feed a directive that draws a sunburst using d3. As I mentioned before, the chart gets drawn fine, but I am still getting this.

EDIT:

It looks like the recursion is fine, the problem is somewhere in Angular and D3. Here is a js fiddle that demonstrates the issue (in console log). However, note that in my environment, I am not getting the digest error for some reason.

http://jsfiddle.net/wrdrvr/4c6bju7L/20/

Comment: If there are no large objects, then the problem must be unbounded recursion.  If the object graph via that `doc.pivot` map/array contains a cycle, then the recursion will never stop.

Comment: recursion ends because get_facet_pivot_sunburst returns data.

Comment: Primarily: Two things blow the stack: large numbers of stack frames (functions called) or really big objects. @pointy +1

Comment: @browskie I'm talking about the recursion in `parse_item()`.

Comment: Thanks guys, anything I can use to verify this? Still learning JS too. What is a good place for console.trace()?

Comment: @browskie if you can put a breakpoint at the top of `parse_item()` in the browser script debugger, then you can look at the value of `doc`. If you open it up and examine what the values of `doc.pivot` look like, you may be able to find a place where the "pivot" array has a reference to an object that's back *up* the tree, so that the recursion will eventually follow back to the same point. (I'll add an answer with another suggestion.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and here is what I came up with…

The cause of the error is combination of two-way-binding, watch expression and layout function (d3.layout.partition()). In your case, you defined property “data” in directive’s inner scope using two-way data binding and define watch expression for that scope variable. In watch callback the rendering function is invoked by passing the same “data” property of your inner scope.

This data is then used in render function which uses partition layout to calculate coordinates for displaying your data. The calculated coordinates (x, y, and maybe few more params for partition layout) are **added as new properties** to each element in input data structure.

Long story short: **scope.data object is updated in render function** and that triggers watch callback which invokes render function again…

I am not sure what is the best way to fix this but here are few solutions which both worked for me:

1. change data binding to one-way-binding (if that makes sense for your
   app)
2. use angular.copy() to create deep copy of data that you want to
   display using d3 (for example change line 102 in your script to

> scope.render(attrs.id, angular.copy(nd));

Comment: this especially happens if you apply layouts like `treemap` to your bound data

Answer (score 0):

Your `doc` structure probably has a *cycle* in it. In a data structure like yours, a cycle is a chain of references that lead around and (eventually) back to a starting point.  In your case, it would be if a `pivot` array somehow contained a reference to a "doc" object back up towards the top of the structure.

What you could do as an experiment is add a "tag" to each "doc" object. If you enter `parse_item()` with a "doc" object whose tag is set, then you know you've hit a cycle:

```
function parse_item (doc) {
  if (doc["@tag"]) throw new Error("Cycle detected");
  doc["@tag"] = true;
  ops++;
  var t = {'name' : doc.value, 'size' : doc.count, 'children': []};
  for (piv in doc.pivot) {
    t.children.push(parse_item(doc.pivot[piv]));
  }
  return t;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pointy, I tried this and didn't see the error pop up. I am pretty sure the data is fine because a) I manually reviewed the data, b) The main function returns and the graph gets rendered, which means that recursion completes fine. I am going to keep looking....

Comment: @browskie well, if you're getting that error, then *some* code *somewhere* is probably stuck similarly. It may not be this code, and if the test didn't detect it then you know that wasn't the spot.

Comment: Thanks Pointy, looks like recursion is fine, it is something in D3/Angular. Sorry for misleading. I updated the post and added a link to a fiddle.